# Unable to install an APK file downloaded from a webserver

Tags: applications, installation

Im trying to download an apk file for a game that I cant access on Play store, but whenever I try it keeps saying APP NOT INSTALLED or there was a problem with the package, I read about a thing where sometimes it tries to install it into the SD card which I don't have a.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons why you don't see an app in Google PlayStore:

1. The app is not available in your country. In such a case you may be able to install the app manually via APK.
2. The app is not compatible with your device. If that is the case you can do what you want but the app installation will always fail. Unfortunately the on-device APK installer doe snot display the error message to you so it is not easy to understand why the installation fails. If you have Android Debug Bridge enabled (`adb`)  you can try to install the APK from your PC via USB and adb (`adb install <apkfilename>`). Then you will see an more detailed error message why the installation fails (e.g. Android version too old or other hardware features required by the app are not available).